# Android media3 Gradle 8.4 AGP 8.3.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-media3

I've been using media3 in an Android app for the better part of a year.  Yesterday I updated gradle to 8.4 and the Android Gradle Plugin to 8.3.0.  I ran it through a battery of tests, including running a qa build that obfuscates it.   Everything looked fine.  I published it.  It was a crashfest.   Crash-free users 5%.  Ugh.  As soon as we make connection to the service (as far as I can tell, remember I can't reproduce this locally).

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Illegal class access: 'G2.c2' attempting to access 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.ImmediateFuture' (declaration of 'G2.c2' appears in base.apk)
   at androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionStub.lambda$queueSessionTaskWithPlayerCommandForControllerInfo$13(MediaSessionStub.java:338)
   at androidx.media3.session.ConnectedControllersManager.lambda$flushCommandQueue$2(ConnectedControllersManager.java:277)
   at androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionImpl.lambda$callWithControllerForCurrentRequestSet$3(MediaSessionImpl.java:318)
   at androidx.media3.common.util.Util.postOrRun(Util.java:761)
   at androidx.media3.session.ConnectedControllersManager.flushCommandQueue(ConnectedControllersManager.java:271)
   at androidx.media3.session.ConnectedControllersManager.flushCommandQueue(ConnectedControllersManager.java:252)
   at androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionStub.lambda$flushCommandQueue$64(MediaSessionStub.java:1653)
   at androidx.media3.common.util.Util.postOrRun(Util.java:761)
   at androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionStub.flushCommandQueue(MediaSessionStub.java:1651)
   at androidx.media3.session.MediaControllerImplBase$FlushCommandQueueHandler.flushCommandQueue(MediaControllerImplBase.java:3290)
   at androidx.media3.session.MediaControllerImplBase$FlushCommandQueueHandler.handleMessage(MediaControllerImplBase.java:3283)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8294)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
```

None of my code is in the stacktrace (that's always fun). I couldn't be the only one using media3 and new versions of the tools, could I?  One thing to note, I publish an app bundle, the play store builds the actual apks.   I'm using media3 1.2.1 (and have been for a few release without any big issues)  I thought it might be some other change I made, but reverting the build tools definitely fixed it.  I made one internal release where that was the only change, and that's the one to starting working again.

So my big question is why?   Android Studio is hounding me to update the tools.  But I really need to know what happened and what to do about it.  Since it works locally (even with minify on), it sure feels to R8/Proguard issue.  Its been a while since I've hit R8/Proguard issues that I couldn't reproduce with qa build (which is basically a release build signed with the debug key).

Comment: Ah, something just occurred to me, I should be able to unpack and compare bad and working apks.

Comment: unpacking the good and bad apks, the big thing that jumps out at me is the bad one's classses.dex is about 200k smaller.  Which is suspicious, but doesn't really tell me what to do to fix the issue.

Comment: This is the R8 version I was using before (and I'm back to using now):
8.2.47 (build 62baf24ba2b71f4e5bc04c7f01930bc5d47b02be from go/r8bot (luci-r8-custom-ci-archive-0-19z6))

Comment: The new R8 version is: 8.3.36 (build 737a6b43d31f334c0f7c91063ab721eeb08c1beb from go/r8bot (luci-r8-custom-ci-archive-0-q5sx))   I plan to try the new gradle and AGP version, but pin R8 at the old version.

Comment: Sure enough the new gradle, and Android Gradle Plugin work, if I pin the version of R8 back to one I was previously using.